# Moving code from Ruby 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I have a problem moving Rails code from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2. I do not understand the behaviour of Ruby.

I have an Array with one element (a string).

```
my_var = [“Bla blubb and foo bar”]
```

Then I call:

```
some text #{my_var}
```

In Ruby 1.8 I get `some text Bla blubb and foo bar`.

In Ruby 1.9 I get `some text [\"Bla blubb and foo bar \"]`

Why is there the difference? How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling to_s on an array of strings. In 1.8 that is equivalent to calling join, in 1.9 it is equivalent to calling inspect.
To get the behavior you want in both 1.8 and 1.9, call join instead of to_s.

Answer (score 2):

The discrepancy you're running into is related to the way Ruby is converting an array into a string across different versions. Before 1.9, Ruby would represent the array by just concatenating the strings in the array. In 1.9 (and presumably, onwards) Ruby represents the array in a more code-like format. It makes quite a bit more sense to do it this way, and it encourages you to say what you mean explicitly.